# React Bootstrap Slider Set Attributes Dynamically

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, bootstrap-4, attributes, slider

For the control React Bootstrap Slider, https://github.com/brownieboy/react-bootstrap-slider, is there a way to set attributes dynamically. For example, like setting the control to be disabled after the slideStop event?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. change: `disabled="disabled"` to :

```
disabled={this.state.disabled ? "disabled" : ""}
```

`disabled` is a state variable and you can set it with : `this.setState({disabled: false})`

Comment: I added the disabled attribute with the conditional statement for the control. I am getting a message that says cannot read property of ‘state’ undefined. Where should the disabled state variable be set? Thanks!

Comment: @SunSunKu it says `cannot read property ‘state’ of undefined`. this mean this is undefined. there is two ways to create components in react, one is using classes, second is using functions. if your component is a functional component , you should use `setState` method to create a state variable. search for `create state variables in react.` you should first create a state variable, then bind it to disabled property.

Comment: I was using functions method I think, using useState and have resolved the situation using that. Thanks!

Comment: @SunSunKu yes if `useState` fixed it, it means that you was using `functional component` style. No problem, happy coding.